# REST API stops if user changes pages

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I've been trying to find an answer to this but having trouble so here goes.

I have made some REST APIs.

My platform allows users to sync their Mailchimp subscribers to their account. I'm trying to let this run in the background (hence the decision to create APIs to talk to Mailchimp and suck in their user data).

At present when they log in and hit the first page, I run an ajax call to a file on our server, eg mailchimp.php

This file then calls our own API (on a different subdomain), which then does all the talking with Mailchimp and updates the users data in the database accordingly.

Everything works fine, except when the user moves to a new page.

How can I get the REST API on our sub domain to keep running until it finishes, without the user needing to wait?

One thing to note is if they leave the original page open and goto a new page in a new tab, it keeps running fine.

So I feel like it has something to do with the ajax call being terminated when they change pages? But I didn't think that would stop the REST API from finishing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens with in progress Ajax request on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449700/what-happens-with-in-progress-ajax-request-on-page-reload)

Comment: try to use ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0);

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, sorry try that where? 

Is it a rest api configuration point that gets made before the call is sent?

Comment: in your php script, perhaps mailchimp.php

Comment: A robust solution might be to write the request to a queuing system, such as RabbitMQ, and create an internal polling service to pull those requests from the queue and process them into Mailchimp. This would allow you to handle exceptions from the Mailchimp API and reprocess messages accordingly.

Comment: I tried implementing the above ignore_user_abort and set_time_limit but it didn't seem to have any impact.