# Do POST requests expire after no response from server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on setting a timer on my server when a `POST` request is made to our API using `setTimeout()`.  After the timer is executed and sends a `200 OK` response, I want to make updates to some of the DOM elements in my application.  My question is, if the timers are set for long periods of time, such as 30+ minutes, will the `POST` request expire and send a `400` response instead, or will it wait indefinitely until the response is made?  My guess is that it will expire, but I'm not 100% sure.  If so, how can I make sure that the response will be received by the client after the timer has executed?

Here is the code that will be executed in the POST request:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   io.emit('insertWaitTime',{AlertID: req.body.AlertID, Time: null});
   io.emit('updateStep',{AlertID: req.body.AlertID, Step: req.body.NextStep}, (res) => {
      if(!boolean){
       console.log("ERROR: /api/setTimer: Could not update alert");
      }else{
       res.status(200).send({
         Message: "SUCCESS: timer was executed",
         Status: 200
       })
      }
  })
}, (60000 * req.body.Minutes));
```

After 200 response then I would update my DOM elements client side:

```
let timerObj = {
 Minutes: 15
 AlertID: this.props.AlertID,
 NextStep: this.props.NextStep,
}

axios.post('/setTimer', timerObj, (res) => {
  // do all dom updating after good response

  console.log(res);

  if(res.Status === 200){
   document.getElementByID('myel').style.display = 'none';
  }

})
```

I need this timer to be set server side because this could be called multiple times and would not be appropriate to set client side as it could cause major side effects.  If anyone has ideas on whether or not this will work, or if I have to go a completely different route, I would appreciate it immensely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After Node.js v13.0.0 the default timeout changed from 120s to 0 (no timeout)

You can set a timeout on the client-side using Axios module as below:

```js
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: 'http://example.com/api',
  timeout: 1000 * 5, 
})
  .then(response => {
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Or setting a server timeout

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Test');
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
server.timeout = 2000;
```

Comment: Wow I never even thought about setting a timeout inside the axios request.  This might be a better option than calling ```setTimeout()``` inside the POST request.

Comment: Would this cause an issue if the user were to refresh the page though?

Comment: If the page reloads, refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449700/what-happens-with-in-progress-ajax-request-on-page-reload

Comment: Ok, so it looks like if the page is refreshed that there is no way to get the response from that ajax request.  The request will be sent right away, and will execute from the server side which is fine, but it gets tricky when I need to get the response back from that request.